# Loading message without able to add component

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm new to Java and Netbeans. I have created a Java project with a JFrame but sometimes when I open design for the JFrame I can't add controls or see what I have previously added and it gives a me loading message which sometimes open normally. I have searched for a solution but have come up empty.

[image]

Comment: how your code look like?

Comment: thanks for replying , what do you mean by the code looks like ? i just added some controls in the Frame and after some minutes re-open project and couldn't see what i added or couldn't even add any new control

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Netbeans is 8.0.2 (I think), you'll need to check the logs to determine what's going on, it's possible that Netbeans encounter an error while trying to load the form, try performing a clean and build first

Comment: Thanks for replying , I'm using netbeans 7.0.1 is that a problem ? or is there anything should i add .

Comment: i got this warning warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
1 warning

Comment: you need to set the bootclasspath.javac -bootclasspath /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar \
      -source 1.7 Main.java

Comment: thanks but I'm on ubuntu . you mean in bashrc file like export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
and the version of netbeans 7.0.1 can work with jdk1.6 or higher ?

Comment: javac -source 1.7 -bootclasspath "$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/rt.jar" Main.java
Tested on Ubuntu 14.04 for Oracle Java 7 and 8.

Comment: i'm working in eclipse too , i've projects depened on jdk1.6 so i make it default but i want to try netbeans so i got the problem with versions . so should i make one version only is the general for any IDEs or can i make every project work on specific version

Answer (score 0):

I installed netbeans from the website of netbeans as I installed it using terminal `sudo apt-get install netbeans` , the problem solved without any hanging and everything is OK

the problem wasn't in versions of `jdk` as i tried to use another `jdk` but not useful for me